# C# ¿Hay alguna forma de usar elementos de un Form en otro Form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Verán. Estoy haciendo un formulario pero como se muestra en la imagen del boton "ingresar datos" quiero ingresar los datos pero que se vean en otro formulario para que sea mas estético el proyecto pero me dice que no existe en el contexto actual (si se porque no existe) asi que quiero saber una forma de relacionar los dos forms para poder usar los DataGridView y mostrarlos. No se si me di a entender. Gracias :C[image: A la derecha están los forms y al izquierda lo que no me lee :C]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo va como texto, las imagenes son dificiles de ver. Dicho esto, porque no le pasas la informacion al otro form, y que el otro form se encargue de llenarse?

Comment: Recuerda que debes aportar un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Como dice el artículo: "**NO uses imágenes de código**. Copia el texto de tu código, pégalo en la pregunta, y después aplícale formato de código. Esto ayuda a que todos podamos leer y probar tu código de una forma mas sencilla."

Comment: No, no te diste a entender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UNA FORMA SENCILLA DE PASAR VALORES ENTRE FORMULARIOS ES LA SIGUIENTE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el botón de tu primer formulario instancias el formulario 2 y pasas por parámetro los valores que desees.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Boton enviar
        Form2 frm = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Ahora en el segundo formulario recibes los parámetros

```
    public Form2(string valor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = valor;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]